# How to properly close a JdbcTemplate DataSource connection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I want to create a one-shot database connection, based on spring classes.
To prevent spring loading the datasource on startup, I create it explicit when needed (only occasionally). I don't need any connection pooling, transactions and stuff like that.

```
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource(props.getUrl(), props.getUsername(), props.getPassword());
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    jdbc.execute(...);
```

Question: how can I afterwards close/destroy the datasource and any open connections explicit?

Comment: the connection is already closed. Also you shouldn't do this as creating both the `DriverManagerDataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` are costly (slow) operations. So you are really better of creating them at startup. That and you really shouldb't be using the `DriverManagerDataSource` for production (it is slow and won't reuse connections).

Comment: So which class should I then use for one-shot single execution connections? I don't want to create the ds on startup (because in my case the db might even be not available on startup. And I don't want spring to check it either). I serves just for a routine that executes let's say once a week.

Comment: @membersound core JDBC API.

Comment: Well, as performance is not of interest for my rare running job, then I'd better use the simple two-liner spring class at cost of some ms performance.

Comment: If you don't want the Spring to check for it (I assume you're having a Spring Boot application), just exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. With respect to "I don't want to create the ds on startup" - maybe you can introduce some builder wrapper and build your connection when you need it? to be honest, I don't understand why you don't want to use Spring's native API.. especially if you mention, that performance is not that important; besides, Spring performs quite well. Maybe also you can consider vanilla/native JDBC? register appropriate object in the context and use when needed. Idk..

Comment: If performance isn't your concern go ahead but for every other solution please use a proper connection pool and pre-configured `JdbcTemplate`. After the use just close the `DataSource` (each `DataSource` has a `close` method).